# How specify fext file name

Tags: vba, excel

when I create my text file using VBA code, I would like the name of the file to be taken from the cell where I can enter the file name I need. How do I reference it in the fso.CreateTextFile command?

thank you

Comment: [Read here on how to specify a string name using that command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). You can use other VBA methods to set that string equal to a cell address in a worksheet.

Comment: Still having trouble. Below is my code and instead of testfilename.txt I want the name to be taken from cell M1 in my sheet.
How do I reference it?

Sub SilverIssueAm()
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\mary_brown\Desktop\VBA\testfilename.txt")
  
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Reference the range in the fso object...

```
Sub textfile()

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(Range("B9"), True)
    a.WriteLine ("This is a test.")
    a.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Still having trouble. Below is my code and instead of testfilename.txt I want the name to be taken from cell M1 in my sheet.
How do I reference it?

Sub SilverIssueAm()
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\mary_brown\Desktop\VBA\testfilename.txt")
  
End Sub

Comment: Try the script that WinginSue has kindly provided

Comment: @iwonarm, Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\mary_brown\Desktop\VBA\" & Replace(Range("B9").Text, ".txt", "") & ".txt", True)